# How to skip one Tab in MUI

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to skip one position in MUI Tabs using ReactJS?

```
<Tabs
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    textColor="secondary"
    indicatorColor="secondary"
    aria-label="secondary tabs example"
  >
    <Tab value={0} label="Page 1" />
    <Tab value={1} label="Page 2" />
    <Tab value={null} label="Add Content" />
    <Tab value={2} label="Page 3" />
    <Tab value={2} label="Page 4" />
  </Tabs>
```

Comment: What do you mean by skip? Don't want to show it?

Comment: I want that value={null} is not to be selected as a position in the tab but it is clickable for another event function